# How can I list only non-empty files using ls?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell, ls

How can I list (using `ls`) all files that are not empty (size > 0) using linux?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'd use `find dirname -not -empty -ls`, assuming GNU find.

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Probably because the asker asked for `ls` and you used `find` ;) I upped though... It's a proper solution

Comment: If you use "find . -not -empty -ls" it will also include the current directory (ie "." in it's output), to just include the current files use "find . -type f -not -empty -ls"

Answer (score 21):

This is a job for [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) ls is not powerful enough.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -size +0 -print
```

`-maxdepth 1` - this tells find to search the current dir only, remove to look in all sub dirs or change the number to go down 2, 3 or more levels.

`-size +0` this tells find to look for files with size larger than `0` bytes. `0` can be changed to any size you would want.

`-print` tells find to print out the full path to the file it finds

**Edit:**
Late addition: You should probably also add the `-type f` switch above. This tells find to only find files. And as noted in comments below, the `-print` switch is not really needed.

Comment: To avoid a warning you should place `-maxdepth 1` before `-size +0`. Also `-print` is the default action, so it's not needed.

Comment: @cYrus - No warnings for me (cygwin)

Comment: Implementations of `find` vary a lot in terms of what valid options are and where they can go. GNU `find` (which is awfully common) *will* produce a warning if you put `-size` before `-maxdepth`.

Answer (score 14):

```
ls -l | awk '{if ($5 != 0) print $9}'
```

If you are intent on using `ls`, you need a little help from `awk`.

Answer (score 10):

`find dirname -type f ! -empty`

Answer (score 10):

Ls has almost no option to filter files: that's not its job. Filtering files is the job of the shell for simple cases (through globbing) and the job of find for complex cases.

In zsh, you can the `L` globbing qualifier to retain only files whose size is >0 (the `.` qualifier restricts to regular files):

```
ls *(.L+0)
```

Users of other shells must use find. With GNU find (as found mostly on Linux):

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -empty -exec ls {} +
```

A POSIX-compliant way is:

```
find . -type f -size +0c -exec ls {} + -o -name . -o -prune
```

If `ls` wasn't just an example and you merely intend visual inspection, you could sort by size: `ls -S`.

Answer (score 3):

```
 $ find /* -type f ! -size 0
```

will work better if you want all non empty files, rather than just directories.

Answer (score 2):

Bash 4.0+

```
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
for file in **/*; do  test -f "$file" && [[ -s "$file" ]] && echo "$file"; done
```